# Swift passing variables into UItableCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to pass a variable into UITableViewCell. currently im using `mycell.myvar = "mystring"` This is not working are there any other ways to make this work. the example below should print "hello" but it does not work

cellForRow

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.reuseCell, for: indexPath) as! CustomFormCellTextField
        cell.myString = "hello"
        return cell
    }
```

myCell

```
class CustomFormCellTextField:UITableViewCell {
    var customTextField:JVFloatLabeledTextField = JVFloatLabeledTextField()
    var myString:String = String()
     override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print(myString)
            self.addSubview(customTextField)
            constrain(self,customTextField) { (cell,row) in
                row.left == cell.left
                row.right == cell.right
                row.top == cell.top
                row.bottom == cell.bottom
            }
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with more information and some code. Your question is very vague. Are you trying to set a label with your string? What data type is `myvar`? Where are you calling `mycell.myvar = "mystring"`? Is your cell a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: you should post code for mycell's class and tableview data source method for this particular line of code.

Comment: ...Does your cell class *do* anything with `myString`?

Comment: please take a look at the revised question

Comment: @NobodyNada i just print it but it does not print

Comment: Does it print anything?  That is, is `init` being called?

Comment: @PhillipMills it does not print any anything. When you mention init, the cell already have `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` can you give more detail about that.

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on your print statement.  See whether it ever gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CustomFormCellTextField put this:

```
var myString: String? {
    didSet {
        guard let text = myString else { return }
        print(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is work but makes no sense to why it work in `didset` and not work on `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) }` It would be better to have it in the init block

Comment: @pprevalon The first issue is that the init call is called before dequeueReusableCell. When you create the text field in init, the string is always nil. The second issue is that init is only called the first time a cell object is displayed. As cells are scrolled off screen, `prepareForReuse` is called and they are reinserted at the bottom of the table view without being dealloced or reinitialized. Look into how cell dequeuing works for more information.

Comment: @skladek thats makes sense Thank you.